# Include functions for other projects in C

Tags: c, makefile, header-files

I am having difficulties with something that should be pretty basic but it just won't work.

I have two projects, let's say A and B. I am trying to include a function from B in A.

Project B:
I have a header file (my_file.h):

```
#ifndef my_file_H_
#define my_file_H_

int my_func();

#endif
```

The accompanying C file (my_file.c):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <my_file.h>

int my_func()
{
   return 1;
}
```

In project A:
I have a Makefile which includes the path to my_file.h, this seems to be working properly as intelisense is not giving me an error on the line #include "my_file.h" in Project A, and when I give it the wrong path it does. Also when I hover over the call to my_func, in project A, VS Code pops up the correct definition from project B for it which seems to imply everything is being included properly. When I make the project I get no compile time error but I do get a link error.

My make file linking script:

```
gcc -llibs -o my-exec obj/my_project_a_file.o
```

Where `libs` are all the libraries I am linking, `my-exec` is the executable file I am producing, and `my_project_a_file` is the object file created during compilation (this does get created fine without error as mentioned)

Link error:

```
In function 'my_project_a_file':
/path/to/file/my_project_a_file.c: undefined reference to 'my_func'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [my-exec] Error 1
```

Comment: Is my_file.c in the libs you are linking, or do you need to include that as well?

Comment: You need to tell the compiler to compile`my_file.c` and then link with `my_file.o`. Since it is not a part of your current project, the compiler has no idea it needs to do so.

Comment: `#include <my_file.h>` -> `#include "my_file.h"`

Comment: You need to link the code from `my_file.o` (compiled from `my_file.c`) with your program from Project A.  Consider whether to create `$HOME/lib` and whether to create a library, `libmine.a` in there containing `my_file.o`.  You can then link with `-L$HOME/lib -lmine` at any time.  You could create a directory `$HOME/inc` (or `$HOME/include`, but I've never understood why `include` wasn't shortened to `inc` like `library` was shortened to `lib`, etc), and put the header in there.  You then add `-I$HOME/inc` to the compilation flags.

Comment: @doctorlove no I shouldn't need to include the .c file

Comment: @Lundin in "Project A" I do have the include in quotes not square brackets, I changed "Project B" to the same but that didn't resolve my issue

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks! Is there a way to include the external object file without creating a library or is this the only way?

Comment: The library is the long-term way to deal with it.  Over the years you'll build up useful functions that can be reused.  In the 40-odd years I've been working, I've built up a library with over 400 source files and headers.  Some of them are used a lot; most of them are used occasionally; some are irrelevant now (though most of those are in a separate directory of obsolete files).  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ However, you can arrange for the `my_file.c` source code to be compiled to `my_file.o` and then add `my_file.o` to the linking command line.  The details of how to do that vary depending on whether you're using makefiles or an IDE of some sort.  You can consider making symlinks from your code in project B to the directory for project A. You could make hard links, but that's unlikely to be a good idea given that you will be using version control (you *will* be using version control, won't you!).  Or you could make a one-time copy of the code, but that's a bad idea. …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my man! You did it! As a proof of concept , I added the absolute path to the link objects variable I have and it worked! I know this isn't the permanent solution I just wanted to make sure it would solve me issue. I made my project, ran the app and got the output from the external function. My larger plan is to make a little API that exposes certain data to another project so I think your library suggestion is the right long term solution. Oh and by the way of course I am using version control lol. If you put your comments into an answer I will mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments to an answer, as requested.*</sup>

You need to link the code from `my_file.o` (compiled from `my_file.c`) with your program from Project A. Consider whether to create a directory `$HOME/lib` and a library, `libmine.a` in the directory, initially containing `my_file.o`. You can then link with `-L$HOME/lib -lmine` at any time. You could create a directory `$HOME/inc` (or `$HOME/include`, but I've never understood why `include` wasn't shortened to `inc` like `library` was shortened to `lib`, etc), and put the header in there. You then add `-I$HOME/inc` to the compilation flags.

> Thanks! Is there a way to include the external object file without creating a library or is this the only way?

The library is the long-term way to deal with it. Over the years you'll build up useful functions that can be reused. In the 40-odd years I've been working, I've built up a library with over 400 source and header files. Some of them are used a lot; most of them are used occasionally; some are irrelevant now (though most of those are in a separate directory of obsolete files).

However, you can arrange for the `my_file.c` source code to be compiled to `my_file.o` and then add `my_file.o` to the linking command line.

The details of how to do that vary depending on whether you're using makefiles or an IDE of some sort.

You can consider making symlinks from your code in project B to the directory for project A. You could make hard links, but that's unlikely to be a good idea given that you will be using version control (you *will* be using version control, won't you!). Or you could make a one-time copy of the code, but that's a bad idea too.

> You did it! As a proof of concept, I added the absolute path to the link objects variable I have and it worked! I know this isn't the permanent solution; I just wanted to make sure it would solve my issue. I made my project, ran the app and got the output from the external function. My larger plan is to make a little API that exposes certain data to another project, so I think your library suggestion is the right long-term solution. Oh, and by the way, of course I am using version control. If you put your comments into an answer, I will mark it as the correct solution.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `#include <my_file.h>` and `#include "my_file.h"` is:

- `#include <my_file.h>` means "go look in the library installation directory for `my_file.h`".
- `#include "my_file.h"` means "look in the current directory (in some compiler and OS-specific manner) for `my_file.h` and if you didn't find it, then go look into the library installation directory as well".

For your own headers and libraries, you should always be using `#include "my_file.h"`.

Comment: "undefined reference" is a linking error. There is no preprocessing error in the question.

Comment: In Project A where I was including the external header I did use quotes, in Project B I did not and I did change that but the problem persists.

Comment: Although valid advice, this is mostly tangential to the linking problem.